# How to add yes or no confirmation pop up after enter the clear shopping cart.Now its directly clear the cart

Tags: magento2, cart

How to make yes or no confirmation popup after clicking the clear shopping cart. Now it's clearing the cart without confirmation.

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**  @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart */
<?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
<form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>"
      method="post"
      id="form-validate"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
      class="form form-cart">
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
<div class="cart table-wrapper<?php echo $mergedCells == 2 ? ' detailed' : ''; ?>">
    <table id="shopping-cart-table"
           class="cart items data table"
           data-mage-init='{"shoppingCart":{"emptyCartButton": "action.clear",
           "updateCartActionContainer": "#update_cart_action_container"}}'>
        <caption role="heading" aria-level="2" class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shopping Cart Items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col item" scope="col"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Item') ?></span></th>
                <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Price') ?></span></th>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></th>
                <!--<th class="col subtotal" scope="col"><span><!--?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subtotal') ?></span></th>-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="cart main actions">
    <?php if ($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
        <a class="action continue"
           href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>"
           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')); ?>">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Continue Shopping') ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="submit"
            name="update_cart_action"
            data-cart-empty=""
            value="empty_cart"
            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')); ?>"
            class="action clear" id="empty_cart_button">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?></span>
    </button>
    <button type="submit"
            name="update_cart_action"
            data-cart-item-update=""
            value="update_qty"
            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')); ?>"
            class="action update">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="update_cart_action_container" data-cart-item-update=""/>
</div>
</form>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.order.actions') ?>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('shopping.cart.table.after'); ?>
```

Comment: you can handle by using jquery. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881706/jquery-dialog-confirm-the-click-on-a-submit-button

Comment: you resolved this ?? i want to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use confirm on onClick event of clear shopping cart button like below:

```
<button type="submit"
        name="update_cart_action"
        data-cart-empty=""
        value="empty_cart"
        title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')); ?>"
        class="action clear" id="empty_cart_button"
        onclick="confirm("Are you sure want to clear cart");"
        >
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?></span>
</button>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

@hardik's answer works but you still need to add:

```
onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to clear cart?')){}else{
    event.preventDefault()};"
```

To his answer to stop the button from still submitting.